# Range preserving matrix derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, nonlinear-analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $M(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be a matrix-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^d$
and let $F(x) = M(x)x$.

Suppose $M(x)$ is differentiable at $x$ and the rank of $M$ is constant for an openset $\Omega$ where $x \in \Omega$.

**Q**: I want to know the conditions under which
$$
col(\nabla F(x)) = col(M(x))
$$
is true.

**My attempt**:
Since
$$
\nabla F(x) = M(x) + \textbf{D}M(x) \cdot x,
$$
where $\textbf{D}M(x)$ is the Frechet derivative,
it suffices to figure out when
$$
col(\textbf{D}M(x) \cdot x ) \subset col(M(x))
$$
is true.
But I am not sure how to go from here.

Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{col}(\cdot)$?

Comment: @user1551 It is the column space of the matrix.